# Spring Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Tags: java, spring, exception

I'm trying to load my `postgresql` db's table information not using traditional spring mvc pattern but also use `java compiler` function to make class into internal project directory & reload whole project that System can Recognize new class & method

**When I'm using simple calculation class into this mechanism, it works**(just for test)

**But when I alternativly using method which I set up for loading DB**(DAO,SERVICE),

**system can't read my method**

**Here is the Error Code**

```
12월 02, 2020 3:29:57 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
심각: 경로 [/inspect]의 컨텍스트 내의 서블릿 [dispatcher]을(를) 위한 Servlet.service() 호출이, 근본 원인(root cause)과 함께, 예외 [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: kr.com.inspect.rule.Test.getMemberList(kr.com.inspect.service.impl.MemberServiceImpl)]을(를) 발생시켰습니다.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: kr.com.inspect.rule.Test.getMemberList(kr.com.inspect.service.impl.MemberServiceImpl)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2108)
    at kr.com.inspect.rule.RuleCompiler.runObject(RuleCompiler.java:127)
    at kr.com.inspect.controller.PostgreController.testRun(PostgreController.java:185)
```

### Of course, I'm googling for this Error Situation

1. In the compile status system can read your method, but when it is trying to read method, it doesn't work
2. Parameter can be the Issue of this problem

---

In case 1. I physically divide the functions which create function & run function in controller.

In case 2. The method which stands for Test have the same parameter(List) as MemberServiceImpl.getMemberList

please don't ask me why are you doing stupid things. That's why I am here.

I'm sorry that my English is poor

### Please Help

More classes Information which I made

Controller

```
    /**
     * 클래스 파일 생성
     * @return 디렉토리 값 반환
     * @throws Exception 예외 처리
     */
    @PostMapping("/xlsxDir")
    @ResponseBody
    public String xlsxDir () throws Exception{
        RuleCompiler test = new RuleCompiler();

        System.out.println("button clicked");
        // report 패키지의 TestRuleCompiler 클래스를 호출하는 테스트 소스
        String str ="\t\tTestRuleCompiler testRuleCompiler = new TestRuleCompiler();\n" +
                "\t\tint result = testRuleCompiler.Test(list);\n" +
                "\t\treturn result;\n";
        // jsonLogs 읽어오는 소스
//      String str ="\t\tList<Metadata> jsonLogs = postgreService.getMetadata();\n\t\tSystem.out.println(jsonLogs.get(0));\n\t\tSystem.out.println(\"success\");";
        // java 파일 컴파일 후 class 로드하는 메서드 호출

        //Object obj = 
        test.create(str, memberService);
        return "true";
    }
    
    /**
     * 클래스 파일 실행
     * @return 디렉토리 값 반환
     * @throws Exception 예외 처리
     */
    @PostMapping("/testRun")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testRun () throws Exception{
        RuleCompiler rc = new RuleCompiler();

        System.out.println("button clicked");
        
        Test test = new Test();
        // Test.class 안의 runMethod 메서드 실행하는 메서드 호출
        List<Member> rst = rc.runObject(test, memberService);
        System.out.println("result : " + rst);
        return "true";
    }
```

class TestRuleCompiler

```
package kr.com.inspect.report;

import java.util.List;

import kr.com.inspect.dao.MemberDao;
import kr.com.inspect.dto.Member;

public class TestRuleCompiler {
    
    public MemberDao memberDao;
    
    public int Test(int[] list){
        int result = 0;
        for(int i : list)
            result = result + i;
        return result;
    }
    
    public List<Member> getMemberList() {
        List<Member> list = memberDao.getMemberList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

class RuleCompiler

```
package kr.com.inspect.rule;

import edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.Arrays;
import kr.com.inspect.dto.Member;
import kr.com.inspect.service.MemberService;
import kr.com.inspect.service.PostgreService;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.tools.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class RuleCompiler extends Thread {
    
    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RuleCompiler.class);
    
    // 자바파일 생성하고 컴파일후 class 파일 로드해오는 파일 (이 메서드는 잘 작동됩니다.)
    public Object create(String body, MemberService memberService)throws Exception{
        String path = "/home/namuhwang/Documents/GitHub/spring-db-connect/src/main/java/";
        String classPath = "/home/namuhwang/Documents/GitHub/spring-db-connect/target/classes/";

        // Source를 만들고 Java파일 생성
        File sourceFile = new File(path+"kr/com/inspect/rule/Test.java");
        String source = this.getSource(body);
        new FileWriter(sourceFile).append(source).close();

        // java파일 컴파일 할때 옵션주기
        List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<>();
        // CLASS PATH 추가
        optionList.add("-classpath");
        optionList.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path")+":"+classPath);
//        optionList.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        // CLASS 파일 저장할 디렉토리
        optionList.add("-d");
        optionList.add(classPath);

        // 만들어진 Java 파일을 컴파일
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

        List<String> sources = Arrays.asList(new String[] {path+"kr/com/inspect/rule/Test.java"});

        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostic = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostic, null, null);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnit
                = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(sources);
        System.out.println("before Compile");
        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(
                null,
                fileManager,
                diagnostic,
                optionList,
                null,
                compilationUnit
        );
        Boolean success = task.call();
        System.out.println("after Compile");

        // 기본 comiler run하는 코드 (추후에 삭제 예정)
//        compiler.run(null, System.out, System.out, path+"kr/com/inspect/rule/Test.java");


        System.out.println("before Load");
        // 컴파일된 Class를 Load
        URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new File(classPath).toURI().toURL()});
//        Class<?> cls = Class.forName("kr.com.inspect.rule.Test", true, classLoader);
        Class<?> cls = classLoader.loadClass("kr.com.inspect.rule.Test");
        System.out.println("after Load");

        // Load한 Class의 Instance를 생성
        return cls.newInstance();
//        return (Object)true;
    }


    public String getSource(String body) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        // Java Source를 생성한다.
        // report 패키지의 TestRuleCompiler 클래스를 호출하는 테스트 소스
        sb.append("package kr.com.inspect.rule;\n"+
                "import kr.com.inspect.report.TestRuleCompiler;\n"+
                "public class Test { \n"+
                "public int runMethod(int[] list) {\n")
                .append(body)
                .append("\t}\n}");
        // jsonLog 읽어오는 소스
//        sb.append("package kr.com.inspect.rule;\n"+
//                "import kr.com.inspect.service.PostgreService;\n" +
//                "import kr.com.inspect.dto.Metadata;\n"+
//                "import java.util.List;\n"+
//                "public class Test { \n"+
//                "\tpublic void runMethod(PostgreService postgreService) throws Exception {\n")
//                .append(body)
//                .append("\t}\n}");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // Test.class 안의 runMethod 메서드 실행
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Member> runObject(Object obj, MemberService memberService) throws Exception{
        //int[] list = {1, 2, 3};
        logger.debug("d",obj);
        logger.warn("w",obj);
        logger.error("e",obj);
        logger.info("i",obj);
        logger.trace("t",obj);
        System.out.println(memberService);
        System.out.println(obj);
        Class<?> arguments[] = new Class[]{memberService.getClass()}; //postgreService
        System.out.println(arguments);
        logger.debug("d",obj);
        logger.warn("w",obj);
        logger.error("e",obj);
        logger.info("i",obj);
        logger.trace("t",obj);
        // Source를 만들때 지정한 Method를 실행
        // runMethod 메소드 지정 
        Method objMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod("getMemberList", arguments);
          // 인자로 list를 보냄
        Object result = objMethod.invoke(obj, memberService);

        // postgreService 가 인자로 보내져야 하는데 보내지질 않음
        System.out.println("before Method");
        System.out.println(obj);
        System.out.println(memberService);
          // 문제 부분 (여기서 실행이 멈춤)
        logger.debug("d",obj);
        logger.warn("w",obj);
        logger.error("e",obj);
        logger.info("i",obj);
        logger.trace("t",obj);
        //Method objMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod("runMethod", arguments);
        logger.debug("d",obj);
        logger.warn("w",obj);
        logger.error("e",obj);
        logger.info("i",obj);
        logger.trace("t",obj);
        System.out.println(objMethod);
        System.out.println("after Method");
        System.out.println(obj);
        System.out.println(memberService);
        logger.debug("d",obj);
        logger.warn("w",obj);
        logger.error("e",obj);
        logger.info("i",obj);
        logger.trace("t",obj);
        //Object result = objMethod.invoke(obj, postgreService);
        logger.debug("d",obj);
        logger.warn("w",obj);
        logger.error("e",obj);
        logger.info("i",obj);
        logger.trace("t",obj);
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("after invoke");
        return (List<Member>) result;
    }
}
```

class Test

```
package kr.com.inspect.rule;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import kr.com.inspect.dto.Member;
import kr.com.inspect.report.TestRuleCompiler;
import kr.com.inspect.service.impl.MemberServiceImpl;
public class Test { 
    
    
    public MemberServiceImpl memberServiceimpl;
    
    public int runMethod01(int[] list) {
    
        TestRuleCompiler testRuleCompiler = new TestRuleCompiler();
        
        int result = testRuleCompiler.Test(list);
        return result;
    }
    
    public List<Member> getMemberList() {
        
        TestRuleCompiler testRuleCompiler = new TestRuleCompiler();
        
        List<Member> result = testRuleCompiler.getMemberList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you skip compile-time checks and re-implement the wheel you run into problems that you wouldn't have otherwise.

Your code

```
Method objMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod("getMemberList", arguments);
Object result = objMethod.invoke(obj, memberService);
```

is calling `getMemberList` of `obj` that is of type `Test` but the `public List<Member> getMemberList()` method of `Test` has no parameters, so probably you shouldn't pass `memberService` as parameter, which incidentally is also mentioned in the exception (`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: kr.com.inspect.rule.Test.getMemberList(kr.com.inspect.service.impl.MemberServiceImpl))`):

```
Method objMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod("getMemberList");
Object result = objMethod.invoke(obj);
```

Comment: Thx but I tried your solution and rerun the project, still get the same error ;(

Comment: So you are calling `obj.getClass().getMethod` without the `arguments` but you still get the error that the method _with_ parameters is not found?

Comment: actually I really don't know that This is parameter problem? or annotation & bean problem? but accroding to log history, system keep saying can't find method

Comment: What do you not understand in "the public List<Member> getMemberList() method of Test has no parameters, so probably you shouldn't pass memberService as parameter"? Your code literally says "Give me the method getMemberList with a parameter of type MemberService" and Java says "There is no such method on Test" which is obviously true.

Comment: My collegue & I solve this problem using class param options that system can read method names
thx for answer my Question